# Translation of “clickbait”

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

*[Clickbait](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clickbait)* is some website content that is aimed at generating advertising revenue, especially at the expense of quality or accuracy, relying on sensationalist headlines to attract click-throughs; such headlines. How would you say clickbait in French?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would say *piège à clics*. It cognates with [*piège à cons*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pi%C3%A8ge_%C3%A0_cons), which means “an obvious trap that can only trap naïve and gullible people”. The carbon translation *appât à clics* would work, too, but sounds less smooth.

Comment: @Amphiteóth La notice date de 2014, l'OQLF prendrait-il ses renseignements sur fr.se? :)

Comment: ref: On pourrait compléter avec ce [lien au GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529745) qui contient les deux termes proposés, en plus de "_aspirateur à clics_" et "_attrape-clics_". // Qui sait! Quand je lis leurs trucs à la _BDL_ je trouve qu'il lise _LBU_ assurément, mais parfois il y a des nuances; on aime la glose. Merci!

Comment: Also _piège à touristes_.

Comment: No, nobody says that sorry ^^ (article/titre) "racoleur" is better

Comment: @amdev Yeah, well I do. Don't be sorry, and feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 7):

Je dirais **putaclic**.

On parlait à l'époque de la presse papier de titre "**racoleur**" ou même de "**putassier**" ([Qui est racoleur et indigne.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/putassier)) si le titre était non seulement racoleur mais également trivial est bas.

Cependant, ces deux termes étaient déjà utilisés avant l'arrivée d'internet, pour des journaux d'information qui devaient justifier avec un minimum de contenu le prix payé par le lecteur pour un exemplaire papier. Il me semble que "*clickbait*" évoque plutôt des "articles" au contenu inexistant, avec des titres du style "*10 photos d'épilation du maillot, la 4ème va vous étonner*" pour lesquels l'objectif est simplement de réussir à faire charger la page, et surtout les publicités, à un internaute qui ne payera pas pour lire l'article.

Il me semble donc que la traduction exacte de "*clickbait*" est "**putaclic**" (mot valise pour **putassier** + **clic**). Ce mot est littéralement utilisé à la place de "*clickbait*" par les français et il est donc parfois utilisé comme un nom ["**Un putaclic**"](http://gameuze.fr/top-10-des-raisons-pour-laquelle-cet-article-est-un-putaclic/) ou comme un adjectif (["**Les titres putaclic**"](http://internetmatuer.com/putaclic-a-travers-le-temps/)). Normalement le français ne permet pas de passer d'un nom à un adjectif ou à un verbe aussi facilement que l'anglais.

Ce terme est beaucoup moins formel que racoleur ou putassier et [certes encore un peu jeune](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=racoleur%2C%20putaclic&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2), mais il reprend l'idée de clic et de racolage vulgaire tout en sous-entendant que le "journaliste" serait prêt à se prostituer pour des clics ("**pute à clic**").

Comment: +1 pour l'analyse et pour l'inventivité linguistique. Ne penses-tu pas qu'on pourrait même garder *racoleur* tel quel parfois ?

Comment: Si le contexte est formel c'est même conseillé !

Answer (score 4):

It actually depends on what use of the term you want (i.e. negative or positive).

For using the term in contexts where these bad connotations you described are welcome (I mean with critical sense, like in an essay), I've already upvoted Evpok's answer, it's perfect, go for it.

If, in the other hand, you need to describe it in a more neutral or technical way, you might want to consider **aimant à clics** ?

Answer (score 3):

*titre aguicheur* as in

[Facebook veut éradiquer les articles au titre aguicheur](https://fr.news.yahoo.com/facebook-veut-%C3%A9radiquer-articles-au-180026852.html)

aguicher :

> Chercher à séduire, à exciter par des manières et une attitude provocantes. *source* : [linternaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/aguicher/)

or alternatively,

*titre racoleur*

> racolage : Comportement qui encourage à obtenir une réaction ou un choix par le biais de paroles ou d'une gestuelle explicite. [linternaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/racolage/)