# Un titre « clickbait » : l'emploi en adjectif ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, adjectifs

En langue anglaise *clickbait* peut être employé comme tel en tant qu'adjectif (*a clickbait article*; [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clickbait?s=t), [OOD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clickbait)) etc. On peut donc facilement imaginer, pour un *titre* (d'une article etc.) par exemple :

> (1) Je trouve le titre... [*clickbait*]. 
>  (2) On a changé le titre parce
>   qu'au final il était peut-être (trop) [*clickbait*].

On a proposé comme [traduction](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11016) de *clickbait*, le [*piège à clics*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11021) (aussi au [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529745)) ainsi que l'[*aimant à clics*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14251) (pour atténuer l'idée de *piège* au besoin).

---

- Comment rend-on *clickbait* en adjectif dans les deux exemples
  ?
- Comment se construit l'emploi comme adjectif du *piège à clic* (*clickbait*) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Le français ne permet pas de passer d'un nom à un adjectif ou à un verbe aussi facilement que l'anglais. Il n'est par ailleurs pas possible de construire un nouveau mot en en accolant deux. Dès lors, je propose l'emploi d'un adjectif existant mais qui s'applique tout à fait à votre exemple (bien que plus générique):

```
un titre racoleur
```

ce terme n'est pas spécifique à l'action de cliquer (s'utilise aussi pour un journal en papier), mais avec le contexte je pense que tout le monde comprend que pour lire plus il faut cliquer dessus: il n'est donc pas nécessaire d'utiliser un néologisme.

Answer (score 10):

On pourrait dire "un titre **putaclic**" ou "un **putaclic**".

Je suis tout à fait d'accord avec la réponse acceptée (titre "**racoleur**") qui est obligatoire si le contexte est formel et qui sera comprise dans tous les cas. J'ajouterais que "**putassier**" ([Qui est racoleur et indigne.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/putassier)) peut également faire l'affaire, si le titre est non seulement racoleur mais également trivial est bas.

Cependant, ces deux termes étaient déjà utilisés avant l'arrivée d'internet, pour des journaux d'information qui devaient justifier avec un minimum de contenu le prix payé par le lecteur pour un exemplaire papier. Il me semble que "*clickbait*" évoque plutôt des "articles" au contenu inexistant, avec des titres du style "*10 photos d'épilation du maillot, la 4ème va vous étonner*" pour lesquels l'objectif est simplement de réussir à faire charger la page, et surtout les publicités, à un internaute qui ne payera pas pour lire l'article.

Il me semble donc que la traduction exacte de "*clickbait*" est "**putaclic**" (mot valise pour **putassier** + **clic**). Ce mot est littéralement utilisé à la place de "*clickbait*" par les français et il est donc parfois utilisé comme un nom ["**Un putaclic**"](http://gameuze.fr/top-10-des-raisons-pour-laquelle-cet-article-est-un-putaclic/) ou comme un adjectif (["**Les titres putaclic**"](http://internetmatuer.com/putaclic-a-travers-le-temps/)). Comme le note @radouxju, normalement le français ne permet pas de passer d'un nom à un adjectif ou à un verbe aussi facilement que l'anglais.

Ce terme est beaucoup moins formel et [certes encore un peu jeune](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=racoleur%2C%20putaclic&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2), mais il reprend l'idée de clic et de racolage vulgaire tout en sous-entendant que le "journaliste" serait prêt à se prostituer pour des clics ("**pute à clic**").

Comment: Je n'avais jamais envisagé que ça venait de "putassier", pour moi c'était la contraction de "pute à clics".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps C'est une interprétation personnelle, je n'ai pas de source pour le lien entre les deux. Il me semble que l'expression n'aurait pas autant de succès si elle ne rappelait pas "putassier" (trop vulgaire, pas assez fine?).

Comment: Je n'ai pas souvenir de l'avoir vu ailleurs que dans des contextes où la vulgarité était de mise.

Answer (score 2):

L'anglais permet de transformer à peu près n'importe quel nom en adjectif (exemple : *a blue-eyed girl*, le mot *eyed* signifiant *aux yeux*). En français, ce n'est pas le cas.

Je propose donc :

> Je trouve que le titre *incite au clic*.
>   On a changé le titre, parce qu'au final il *attirait* peut-être trop *le clic*.

Comment: J'aurais juste édité, mais l'erreur ne fait qu'un caractère, au lieu de 6 : "attirait" et non "attrirait". Par contre, dans le second cas, je trouve la traduction trop gentille : l'idée est que le titre est trop racoleur et qu'il a été changé à cause de cela

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord, c'était une idée, mais je trouve que celle de radouxju est mieux.